# Difference between "faculty member" and "faculty person"

Tags: terminology

I've occasionally heard the phrase "faculty person" used, apparently as an alternative to "faculty member".

Are these exactly equivalent, or are there any subtle differences in meaning, connotation, or usage?  Is there any reason to prefer one to the other in any particular setting?

Comment: Seems unlikely that there is a difference. Note that the US, at one time, had a lot of local dialects. That mostly disappeared in the age of television, though. Still some remnants of it. Some months ago there was an online "test" that would predict where you were from by the words you described things with: "soda" vs "pop", for example.

Comment: It's somewhat reminiscent of the shift to gender-neutral terms for professions, e.g. "fireman" -> "firefighter".  I wondered if perhaps there was something similar here, that one was more inclusive than the other, in a way that I hadn't understood.

Comment: It might be that "person" has become a favorite word lately.

Comment: I've seen ambiguity of the term where sometimes "faculty" is implied to include only tenure-track professors (gathering other research and teaching folks among the "staff"), or perhaps tenure-track and professional track, and other cases where it applies to a broader group. However, I don't recall any place that this distinction rested on inclusion of some other word like "member" or "person".

Comment: The people I've heard it from were native English speakers and fairly senior.  Searching on this site, for instance, I've seen [paul garrett](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/156221/emailing-potential-supervisors-in-the-us-before-submitting-application/158485#158485) use "faculty person", and as far as I can tell, those both apply to him.

Comment: Seems a sizable fraction of the occurrences of "person" here at academia.SE are from Paul: https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22faculty+person%22 whereas "member" is quite common https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22faculty+member%22 - guessing it's just an idiosyncratic synonym not intended to have different meaning.

Answer (score 2):

"Faculty member" is idiomatic.  "Faculty person" is not.  Otherwise there is no difference.